# JDBC MySQL Connector

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have configured mysql-connector.jar file in my java project in Eclipse(Kepler) IDE, I am able to connect to database without any issue. But each time I run the program it gives below error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.driver     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   jdbcTest.JdbcInsert.main(JdbcInsert.java:9)

My Code is as below -

```
package jdbcTest;

import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc", "root", "root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String sql="insert into emp values(101,'Santosh',24,10000)";
        int a=st.executeUpdate(sql);

        System.out.println(a+" Record inserted successfully");
    }
}
```

Please suggest what went wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a capitalization error in your driver name, it should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: Hi javabrett, You are awesome ! Nice observation it resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer correct via the tick if it solved your problem, if that option is available now the question is on-hold.